# Artefacts in texturing in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, texturing

I have used the `Python Imaging Library` to load a `.ttf` font. Here is the code:

```
self.rect = Image.new("RGBA", (600,100), (255,255,255))
self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.rect)
self.font = ImageFont.truetype("font.ttf", 96)
self.draw.text((5,0), "activatedgeek", (0,0,0), font=self.font)
self.texture = self.loadFont(self.rect)
```

Here is the `loadFont()` function of the respective class:

```
def loadFont(self, im):
        try:
            ix, iy, image = im.size[0], im.size[1], im.tostring("raw", "RGBA", 0, -1)
        except SystemError:
            ix, iy, image = im.size[0], im.size[1], im.tostring("raw", "RGBX", 0, -1)

        retid = gl.glGenTextures(1)
        gl.glPixelStorei(gl.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1)
        gl.glBindTexture(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D,retid)
        gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
        gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
        gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.GL_CLAMP)
        gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.GL_CLAMP)
        gl.glTexParameteri(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl.GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, gl.GL_TRUE)
        gl.glTexImage2D(gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,ix,iy,0,gl.GL_RGBA,gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image)
        return retid
```

Here is a snapshot I have taken using `glReadPixels()` unfortunately same as one rendered on the window created using `PyQt`.

[image: Snapshot OpenGL context]

It shows an unwanted border, some artefact. Please help me rectify this.

Comment: Have you tried to create your texture with no mipmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a more reasonable wrap state, such as `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`? I have a strong feeling that this is related to border color beyond the edges of your texture image.

There are a number of approaches you could take to solve an issue like this, ranging from pre-multiplied alpha to an extra texel border around the entire image, but the simplest thing to try would be `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.

`GL_CLAMP` is something of a joke as far as wrap modes go, it does not clamp the range of texture coordinates to texel centers and calamity ensues when the nearest texel becomes the border color. Needless to say, this behavior is usually undesirable.

Comment: i would try this thank you! though what was strange was that I tested the same code on Windows 8, gave me the results I desired, but in Ubuntu 13.10, it didn't perform well.